# Having trouble deleting partial dupliacte rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, distinct

I am trying to delete partial duplicate rows; rows where some key values are the same. To do this i have to choose between which duplicate row to delete based on a col.

Eg: data table

```
col1, col2, col3
1,     1,    1
2,     2,    2
1,     1,    2
2,     2,    3
```

I want to get rid of rows that are duplicate on col 1 and 2 and keep the row that is highest on col3 resulting in

```
col1, col2, col3
1,     1,    2
2,     2,    3
```

I think the way to go is do a select `distinct` statement on `col 1 and 2` but i am having trouble working in the `col3` into the result.

```
SELECT DISTINCT [col1], [col2]  FROM [table]
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

got it thanks to another stackOverflow post ...

```
SELECT * 
FROM [TABLE] a 
     LEFT JOIN [TABLE] a2
         ON a.col3<a2.col3 AND a.col1=a2.col1 and a.col2=a2.col2
WHERE a2.col2 IS NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

```
DELETE t
FROM dbo.test83 t
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
                  SELECT 1
                  FROM dbo.test83 t2
                  WHERE t.Col1 = t2.Col1
                    AND t.Col2 = t2.Col2
                  HAVING MAX(t2.col3) = t.col3
                  )
```

Demo on [**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/86fdc/1)

Also in SQLServer2005+ you can use option with CTE and ROW_NUMBER() ranking function

```
;WITH cte AS
 (      
  SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY t.Col1, t.Col2 ORDER BY t.Col3 DESC) AS rn
  FROM dbo.test83 t
  )
  DELETE
  FROM cte
  WHERE rn > 1
```

Comment: Spot on though, just tested it and it is correct - thanks a mill lad!

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a `UNIQUE INDEX`, like this one:

```
ALTER IGNORE TABLE tablename ADD UNIQUE INDEX idx_name (col1, col2 );
```

This will drop all the duplicate rows, and prevent duplicate insertion in future. You may like to take a backup before running something like this...

Comment: How does it know i want to drop the max Col3?

Comment: Ok im getting an error, 'Unknown object IGNORE' then i remove ignore and i get incorrect sytax near INDEX - ALTER TABLE [TABLENAME] ADD UNIQUE INDEX idx_name ([col1], [col2] );

Comment: i created the index CREATE INDEX PIndex ON [tablename]([col1], [col2] ) Still doesnt solve the issue in itself

Answer (score 0):

Does this select give you the result you are looking for ?

```
select [col1], [col2], max([col3]) from [table3] group by col1,col2
```

Maybe you can insert the result of this select into a table and replace the old table with the  new one ? I think this is probably not the best solution, but maybe this query can help you find what you are looking for.

Comment: no as this does not give me all my other collumns back, col4/5/6/7/8/9 which i should have displayed in the example.